# Yosemite Login screen ignoring login after Screen Saver

Tags: security, screensaver, screen-lock, login-screen

This is regarding a:
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)
2 GHz Intel Core i7
8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

I have a managed, admin, remote account on the Mac.
This is the only account on the Mac.

The Screen Saver (Word of the Day) is set to come up after 30 mintues.
Energy Saver is set to turn off the display after 30 Minutes.

Security setting is: Require password 5 seconds after sleep or screen saver.

I return to the system after 5 seconds since the screen saver has started, but before 30 minutes...

Routinely there is a problem where the login screen (Just offering a PW, not a username) ignores the typed in password.

The password is entered, the return key is hit. The password bullets highlight and the system sits and gives no feedback as to the auth status.
The clock is still running, so the system isn't locked up.

If I sleep the device (Either by closing the MBP or by hitting the power key briefly) then when the login screen comes back up (after reawake) a new set of issues occur.

1. Now the password bullets simply clear whenever the return button is pressed.
2. The restart and change user buttons accept the click and highlight but do nothing. When released they unhighlight.

The only escape from this is a hard reset holding the power button for >5 seconds.

Open to any suggestions.

Comment: Does this happen with any user or just your user?

Comment: @ProfFrnswrth Thanks for the question. I added more details to the question in response. Short answer: Only account on box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the problem here was that the network domain it had been registered had fallen out of sync. The time delay was a network timeout from believing it had access to the Domain controller and the time it didn't receive a response.

Re-enrolling the device in the domain remedied this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a test account on the computer and test it as well. If the issue persist it is a system wide issue. I would reset the SMC on the computer, try to boot into Safe Mode and try there as well. If issue is still persistent reinstall the OS through the recovery partition (you will not lose any of your personal data just reinstalling the OS)

Comment: I hadn't run the standard set of tests yet. Was looking to see if anyone had had similar. The trick will be getting a second user on the system similar to the first. (Have to call IT for another managed account) If any of the standard fixes cover this, I'll give you the specific fix and give you credit

Answer (score 1):

I am having the exact same problem, it started when I installed the 10.10.3 update, since then Apple released 10.10.3 Supplemental update that has helped the issue but has not solved it. Before the supplemental update it would happen every time the machine went to sleep. Now it seems to only happen after I type my password wrong.

This is a late 2013 Macbook Pro, Core i7 w/ 8Gb of RAM, bound to MS Active Directory and I am using my AD credentials with a roaming mobile profile (though the issue seems to happen both on and off my AD network).

Comment: This adds important information about the update and even if it doesn't answer directly, I'm voting it up. If it's really related to typing the password incorrectly and this separates two bugs it could help many figure out what to do in this case.